# Minimizing a function using Lagrange multipliers in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a problem with my MATLAB code that I write to minimize this function with two constraints (one of them is inequality and the other one is equality) with Lagrange Multipliers that use KKT conditions. This the Function :

```
       MIN F = 2*x1^2 + 2*x2^2-6*x1*x2
        ineq=x1+2*x2<=3
        eq=3*x1+x2=9
```

I am personally suspect that my **if Function(statement)** has problem but don't know how to fix that .....

```
    clc
    warning off
    syms x1 x2 u s lambda
    f=2*x1^2+2*x2^2-6*x1*x2;
    g1=sqrt(x1^2*x2)+s^2-0.25;
    H1=x1*x2^2-0.1;
    Lagrange=f+u*g1+lambda*H1;
    Grad=gradient(Lagrange);
    S=solve(Grad);
    S=double([S.x1 S.x2 S.s S.u S.lambda]);M=size(S,1);
      for i=M:-1:1
    if imag(S(i,3))~=0 || S(i,1)<=0 || S(i,2)<=0
      end
    end
    x1=S(:,1);x2=S(:,2);s=S(:,3);u=S(:,4);lambda=S(:,5);
    out=table(x1,x2,s,u,lambda)
    x0=[1 0.5 -0.75];
```

It seems I have a problem because it gives me both write and wrong answers can you help me with that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just eliminate the corresponding row when `if` condition is satisfied using `S(i,:)=[];`

---

**According to your formulation**

The `if` condition should look like this

```
if imag(S(i,3))~=0 || S(i,1)<=0 || S(i,2)<=0
    S(i,:)=[];
end
```

**Solution**

```
out =

  1×5 table

      x1        x2       s      u       lambda 
    ______    _______    _    ______    _______

    0.3393    0.54288    0    3.6349    -2.6402
```

---

> From my point of view your **equality and inequality constraints**
>   formulation are wrong

```
ineq = x1 + 2*x2 <= 3 -------> g1 = x1 + 2*x2 - 3 + s^2

eq = 3*x1 + x2 = 9    -------> H1 = 3*x1 + x2 - 9
```

The `if` condition checks

- if `u`(***modifying*** `g1`) is less than zero or not

or

- if `s` is real number or not

```
for i=M:-1:1
      if imag(S(i,3))~=0 || S(i,4)<0 
      S(i,:)=[];
      end
  end
```

The entire code is as follow

```
syms x1 x2 u s lambda
    f=2*x1^2+2*x2^2-6*x1*x2;
    g1 = x1+2*x2-3 +s^2 ;
    H1 = 3*x1+x2-9;

    Lagrange=f+u*g1+lambda*H1;
    Grad=gradient(Lagrange);

    S=solve(Grad)
 S=double([S.x1 S.x2 S.s S.u S.lambda]);M=size(S,1)

      for i=M:-1:1
          if imag(S(i,3))~=0 || S(i,4)<0 

             S(i,:)=[];

          end
      end

    x1=S(:,1);x2=S(:,2);s=S(:,3);u=S(:,4);lambda=S(:,5);
    out=table(x1,x2,s,u,lambda)
```

**Solution**

```
out =

  1×5 table

    x1    x2    s     u      lambda
    __    __    _    ____    ______

    3     0     0    13.2     -8.4
```

---

> Check your answer using `fmincon` as follow

```
% Check your answer using fmincon 
% Inequality constraint
%ineq = x1 + 2*x2 <= 3
A = [1, 2];
b = 3;
% Equality constraint
%eq = 3*x1 + x2 = 9
Aeq = [3, 1];
beq = 9;
%F = 2*x1^2 + 2*x2^2-6*x1*x2
F = @(x)2*x(1).^2 + 2*x(2).^2-6*x(1).*x(2);

x0 = [0,0];
[x_minimum, Feval] = fmincon(F, x0, A, b, Aeq, beq);
```

**Solution**

```
x_minimum =

    3.0000   -0.0000


Feval =

   18.0002
```

Comment: thanks for your time i really appreciate your help.I am a newbie in Matlab and encountering so many errors and problems .... again thanks alot ... that was very generous of you to share your knowledge and time

Answer (score 0):

how can I solve this problem with MATLAB in the same way as above? Can I also show it on the chart?

fmin(x1,x2 )=(x1-1)^2+(x2-1)^2

H1=x1+x2-4=0;
H2=x1-x2-2=0